# Is the bag in the Manfrotto 7320YB M-Y Compact Tripod Kit with Ball Head/Backpack/Gear Bag bundle weather proof?

Tags: tripod, camera-bag, weather

I want to buy [the Manfrotto 7320YB M-Y Compact Tripod Kit with Ball Head/Backpack/Gear Bag bundle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004C2KDFE) for my Canon 60D

[image]

I want a weather proof or resistant bag since my camera is not weather sealed. I cannot find any information stating if it is or not?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a good rule of thumb for features like this is: if it doesn't proudly declare it, the answer is no.

[Reviews of the bundle on Adorama](http://www.adorama.com/BG732YB482K.html#ProductReviews) contain one which complains that the backpack has a "poor build" and that the fabric that used is "really thin". So that doesn't sound so hopeful. On the other hand, [a reviewer on B&H Photo](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/730062-REG/Manfrotto_732YB_482K_7320YB_M_Y_Compact_Tripod.html) notes: "the bag seems to be constructed fairly well. [...] And there seems to be some weather sealing for the tripod pocket zipper."

But that's a far cry from "weather proof" or even resistant. I think you probably should look elsewhere for that.